# How to sort a multidimensional array in dart using an inbuilt metheod

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, dart, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array(list) in a dart that needs to be sorted how can I achieve this in terms of price. Is there any inbuilt method to do this or do I have to do this with code? is it ok to have both a string and an integer datatype in the same list like below

```
int row = 4;
int col = 4;

var array = List.generate(row, (i) => List(col), growable: false);

//For fill;
array[0][0] = 12;
array[0][1] = "apple";

array[1][0] = 10;
array[1][1] = "drink";

array[2][0] = 15;
array[2][1] = "orange";

array[3][0] = 8;
array[3][1] = "chocolate bar";

array[4][0] = 0;
array[4][1] = "nut";

//I want to sort this array in terms of price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do comparison but you have to convert your index type into int. Check below code

```
array[0][0] = "12";
array[0][1] = "apple";

array[1][0] = "10";
array[1][1] = "drink";

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array.sort((a, b) {
      return int.parse(a[0]).compareTo(int.parse(b[0]));
    });
  }
```

you can reversed your output array by using `array.reversed`

Comment: actually, what are a and b here could you please explain them a little bit? from this code will I be able to sort it in decreasing order according to the price

Comment: a and b are representing current and next index i.e. 0 and 1 - Means 1st value of array ["12", "apple"]. and next value of array ["10", "drink"]

Comment: thank you very much I was confused now I got this

Comment: Glad to help you, Please accept the answer if its works for you.